# Calculate a Generator Matrix with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, matrix

I would like to write a VBA code for a generator matrix. A generator matrix shows the number of borrowers that moved from one rating class to another within a given time frame. It looks like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DubAP.jpg)

The yellow cell means for example that how many borrowers out of the sample moved from rating AAA (at the beginning of the year) to AA (at the end of the year).

In the sample I have 10,000 borrowers, then comes the rating of these borrowers at the beginning of the year (B2:B10001), and the next column shows the ratings at the end of the year (C2:C10001). The rating categories can be AAA, AA, A, BBB, BB, B, CCC/C and D. 
So the data set looks like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpBX2.jpg)

Since the rating ranges in B and C columns can be fixed in the VBA code, only 2 arguments should be choosen manually: the original rating (call it 'm') and the final rating (call it 'n').

So the VBA code should somehow count the number of borrowers that migrated from one rating category to another, where the rating categories would always be selected manually.

Could you help me with this issue?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you write a line of code so far? Where is your problem?

Comment: You state you *'would like to write a VBA code for a generator matrix'* but really all you are looking for is someone to write your code for you aren't you?

Comment: *"Could you help me with this issue?"* Is not a viable question for this site

Comment: @Jeeped Maybe, maybe not. Sometimes people are just looking for detailed guidance on how to write the macro when they don't know how to proceed. From a single question it is hard to tell if they are a nonprogrammer hoping to obtain a complete solution just by asking or if they actually do some VBA programming but just don't know how to ask a good question (and hence need to read [ask] ).

Comment: Please read [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513)

Comment: You should look into writing an UDF that takes the beginning rating and ending rating and returns the intensity and direction (+/-) of the rating change. The rest can be done with Excel functions like COUNTIFS. The problem itself is relatively simple. A tip:   
`Dim ratingCategories() As String    
ratingCategories = Split("AAA|AA|A|BBB|BB|B|CCC/C|D", "|")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you just need a countifs formula, so the yellow cell would have:

=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$10001,"AAA",$C$2:$C$10001, "AA")

Comment: Changing the "AAA" and "AA" is for all the combinations is painful but this solution works.

Comment: Using cell references actually makes Countifs the easiest solution.  `=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$B:$B,Sheet2!D$5,Sheet1!$C:$C,Sheet2!$C6)`   
OR  Depending how you want the matrix to look:
`=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$B:$B,Sheet2!$C6,Sheet1!$C:$C,Sheet2!D$5)`

Comment: Thank you for your quick help, this solution will be fine for me. Some asked if I wanted to get the code written. Well, I have already written a code, but unfortunately it does not work, and I was hoping to get some guidance. But this COUNTIF solution will also be perfect, and I was simply curious how could I do it in VBA. Thank you again for your help :)

Comment: @NorbertHorváth If you want help with the VBA, show the code that you have written even if it doesn't work. Questions like that get a much better response on Stack Overflow, especially if you give relevant information such as what error message (if any) you see when you try to run the code.